# A quest for internet access ( Unidentified network and Error 651 )

Tags: networking, network-adapter, adsl, broadband, adsl2+

I'm stuck with one of the most harsh problems i had to deal with, regarding fixing my computer.Im trying to solve it for days ( have
searched a lot on the web ) and no results so far.
The problem is about network and internet access.

I have a broadband ADSL connection and until this problem showed up, my computer had regular internet access on Windows 7,  with my onboard network card connected to 
the ADSL modem ( TP-LINK TD-8816 ), no routers. Suddenly ( after coming from stand by ),  my pc had no internet access and when i checked the Local Area Connection, the status
showed as Network unidentified, which doesnt even let me access the configuration page of the modem by its ip address.I tried to 
start my ADSL connection ( modem was on bridge mode ) and Windows 7 points me error 651.
I tried to diagnose the problem with Windows and it says my Local Area Connection
doesnt have a valid ip configuration.

Quickly, i pluged my ADSL modem  with the same RJ-45 cable on my Dell netbook to see if the problem was my computer or with the modem.
Then i saw that my Dell's network card was behaving regularly with my modem and i could both access the modem configuration page
as well as  have internet access.

So, imediately i discarded my broadband provider,my modem and the cable as the fault. I was sure the problem was on my PC ( either hardware or software ).
I started with software-,  i tried a lot of things like updating the driver, searching  services like Bonjour or  ##ID_String type ( it didn't have any ), removing IPV6,
installing reliable multicast protocol, assigning the modem gateway ip manually. 
None of these worked.
Then i decided to format my HD and re-install Windows 7 from scratch.
After that, oddly, the problem still persisted. That made me go to the hardware and blame solely my onboard network card  ....
Then i went to buy a new network card. The network card i chose was the Encore ENLGA-1320 , which oddly had the same Realtek PCI GBE controller, seeming exactly like i had bought
my old onboard network card.
So, i installed it and i didnt even have to install any driver because the Encore's driver was the same as my onboard's network card driver.
After connecting the modem to the new network card,  the problem still persists : Network unidentified, and no internet access with error 651.

But then i made some test. I pluged my D-LINK Router on the new network adapter and it recognized it, i was able to access its configuration page.

Not on the old network adapter ( onboard one ), so it suggests my old network adapter was faulty.

Checking the ipconfig /all on the ADSL Modem i get this : [image] , according to the
unidentified network ( after trying to identify for some seconds ).

Then, a second later, changing one end of the RJ-45 cable from the ADSL-modem to the D-Link router, my network adapter quickly identifies
a network and i get a perfectly fine ipconfig /all : [image]

To sum up the confusion :
On one side i get the message that the ADSL modem is okay because even tho it doesnt work on my new network adapter from my Desktop PC,  it works perfectly fine when pluged to my Dell netbook.
But on the other side, i get that my pc software-hardware ( windows and my new network card ) are okay and maybe the problem
is still with the ADSL modem because even tho my new network adapter doesnt recognize the ADSL modem, it recognizes perfectly well my D-Link router ( not giving unidentified network message ).

Any clues ?  Should i buy a new ADSL modem even tho it works on my dell netbook ?

Thanks a lot, it really means a lot  for me to get this figured out.

Comment: Have you talk to your service provider about this problem? A ADSL modems can be configured to allow or disallow certain devices remotely.  Have you made sure you have deleted and remove the device drivers for the old device.  I admit this possability has holes.

Comment: I would suggest the router has the netbook's MAC address registered and not the desktop's. It happened once when I tried to do a similar thing. Hardcoding my MAC address to the laptop's network adapter worked.

Comment: Yes i did talk to the service provider and they pointed the problem as the modem or the network card. Also, i reseted the modem configuration to default several times. Could it still be that it has netbook's MAC adress and not the desktop's ?

Comment: I just went to the configurations page of my modem ( via my netbook Dell ) and under Access Management > Filter, the IP / MAC Adress filter table is empty, so i think that removes that possibility.
Thanks a lot for reading my problem, i really appreciate that

Comment: Even still, MAC addresses are finicky (as they are sometimes used to prevent Internet access in some countries). Try to change your desktop's MAC address to the netbook's. A guide I found in a Google search that seems to cover all basis is [this](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-change-mac-address/).